Books using the axiomatic method
Apart from works on geometry (such as Euclid's Elements and its various translations) and Spinoza's Ethics, has the axiomatic method been used as a means of exploring a certain field or exposing one's thesis? Any examples would be very useful.
I have searched for "ordine geometrico" (which is Latin for "geometric method") on various places online such as Archive.org and Gallica, but all I can find are references to Spinoza.
The relevant Wikipedia entry mentions nothing between Euclid and the 19th century.
Related (but different) questions:

What is the origin of the axiomatic method?
Who made the first (recorded) axiomatic model of nature?


Moder textbooks regarding set theory (e.g. Suppes), probability (Kolmogorov), arithmetic (Peano, Landau).

Regarding physics, see Newton CA da Costa & Francisco Antonio Doria, On Hilbert's Sixth Problem (Springer, 2022)

It may be fruitful to search for the term "axiomata" which was used by Leibniz in his Latin correspondence discussing the meaning of axioms. For example the book  by Daniel Stahl (1645) is titled "Axiomata philosophica" and was taught to Newton (see Ducheyne (2005)).

I recall a peculiar physics book
Information Mechanics by Frederick William Kantor (1977)
He starts with some simple axioms on information and (in 100s of pages of deductions) ends up doing physics ??

This reminds me of The Logical Structure of Mathematical Physics by Joseph Donald Sneed (1938-2020 (1971; revised 1979), a book I got very cheaply (probably around $2 to $3) at a used book store sometime in the late 1970s (I have the 1971 edition). Zbl 324.02001 and Zbl 426.03002 The three diagrams on pp. 176-178 (1971 edition) do seem pretty neat $\ldots$

Cavalieri's book Geometria indivisibilibus continuorum nova quadam ratione promota (1637) was written in such an axiomatic style.  Cavalieri was particularly concerned to present his work in a rigorous style because at the time indivisibles and atomism were under ferocious attack by the catholic hierarchy in general and jesuits in particular.  A useful study of Cavalieri by Hector Manuel Delgado (2017) is now accessible on the web.

Of course, Hilbert, Grundlagen der Geometrie, published in 1899 (Engl. Tr. The Foundations of Geometry).
The Grundlagen contain an axiomatic exposition of geometry in purely synthetic terms. The purpose of the book, as Hilbert says in the introduction,  is “to establish for geometry a complete system of axioms”:

Geometry requires, […] to be coherently founded, only few, simple
fundamental propositions. These fundamental propositions are called
the axioms of geometry.[…] This investigation is a new  attempt to
establish for geometry  a complete system of axioms and as simple  as
possible, and deduce from them the most important geometric
propositions, in order to highlight clearly  the meaning of the
different groups of axioms and the scope of the consequences to be
drawn from the single axioms. .” (Hilbert, cit.  Introduction, my
tr.)


Frege, too, for a similarly-axiomatic attack on arithmetic/number theory?

Yes, axiomatic method was invoked also for arithmetics and number theory, also by Hilbert, think for instance of the axiomatic definition of real numbers.

The other big user of the axiomatic method early on was Archimedes in his book "On Floating Bodies", c. 3rd century BCE.

For the most part, the axiomatic method was used for a lot of physics studies up until 19th century (in the form of geometry). Just to name a few that I've used personally in my studies in Renaissance and Enlightenment era physics:
Euclid's Elements - This one goes without saying, but I'm providing links to free resources on each respective subject.  I love the hyperlink feature in Joyce's version.
Appollonius's Conics - This is a "sequel" to Euclid's Elements as it relies on its initial axioms and propositions to construct conics using a directrix line. Newton relies on these conics proofs to do a lot of heavy lifting in his Principia.  The first link is to the Heath version, but I also like the Besant version as well (especially the Project Gutenburg one that includes hyperlinks within the text).  Both are great.
Practically all of Archimedes - Really interesting stuff. His Equilibrium of Planes was highly influential for early physics as he axiomatically describes the lever law and balancing bodies.  His proof works well with rational (commensurate) quantities, but his proof is questionable when he applies it to irrational (incommensurate) quantities -- Ernst Mach famously critiqued the proof as being logically circular.
Galileo's De Motu - Galileo's early studies on motion relied on axiomatic assumptions of Aristotle's elements.  This one is a great example of how faulty axioms can still lead to correct results.  I'm only aware of a single English (non-digital) translation by Drabkin. Galileo was a huge Archimedes fanboy and often refers to his work.
Galileo's Two New Sciences - Galileo's last publication that birthed modern physics.  This one is interesting because his frustrations with De Motu (on motion) and Le Meccaniche (on mechanics) led him to completely abandon the prevailing theories of his time and start completely from scratch. The axiomatic approach kicks off in the "Third Day" in which he examines uniform motion and accelerated motion, which he then tests his deductions empirically.
Newton's Principia - Probably the most famous physics text that uses an axiomatic method (i.e., Newton's laws) to explain terrestial and celestial motions.
EDIT: I'm gonna toss in Bertrand Russell's Principia Mathematica as the whole point of it was to minimize all of mathematics to a set of axioms and to fix problems in logic and set theory. It requires 86 pages of proofs to show that 1+1=2, which, as commented, the "proposition is occasionally useful."
